# word2vec: how to predict the most likely words and sentences?

Tags: nlp, prediction, n-gram, word2vec

Word2vec by Google has been shown to be powerful in NLP tasks. I am quite new to the tool and unclear about what exactly it can do.

Say we have a sentence: "I will go to New York this weekend."

Based on this sentence, we have many options to transform it. For example:

1) "I will go to New York with my Dad this weekend."

2) "I will go to LA this weekend."

3) "I will not go to New York this weekend."

What I want from word2vec is that, given the basic sentence, how can I predict one of its transformations to be the most likely one? Or, given one transformation, we can calculate the probability on top of the basic sentence.

An extra question is, besides word2vec, are there any other tools can serve the same purpose?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by predicting "one of its transformations to be the most likely one?" ? What is the "most likely" ?

Answer (score 2):

you may want to look at recurrent nets. they have applications in natural language generation.

http://deeplearning4j.org/recurrentnetwork
https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

Also consider Doc2vec, which vectorizes whole sentences instead of single words or short n-grams, and can cluster sentences by similarities.